# What is some game development literature purely in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm mainly interested in the videogames development in pure javascript, since nowadays there's so many books about htm5 and javascript I couldn't find any book about game development with javascript only.

Comment: What is "pure javascript"?  In most cases, Javascript needs HTML to  actually do anything.

Comment: You don't need HTML, you need a way to update the screen. You can do "pure javascript" as long as you have a javascript driver then can do IO

Comment: If you have a specific problem to solve, you should ask that question.  What are you looking for in the literature you're asking for that will help you get what you need done, done?

Answer (score 4):

This question looks like to this one :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506803/good-resources-for-javascript-2d-game-programming

The answer seems to point to useful ressources about Javascript video game programming.

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Unity-Game-Development-Essentials-Goldstone/dp/184719818X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/184719818X)

The book doesn't only focus on javascript since unity supports c# and boo. If you don't want to go the HTML 5 route then an engine like unity would probably be the thing to do. There are others like unity but I'm biased